# SEO - moving subdomain to folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, http-status-code-301, canonical-link

I am moving my blog from a sub-domain - `blog.example.com` to a sub-folder `example.com/blog/`

The URLs and the content are staying exactly the same.

What would be the best SEO-wise action to take, I was thinking the following:

1. Add `rel="canonical"` to sub-domain URLs and let the spiders crawl my pages to become aware of the new links.
2. Add a `301 redirect` from sub-domain to sub-folder.

I understand that there's no point in having canonical if there's a 301 redirect.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank You in advance!

Comment: SEO questions are only on-topic if they involve a specific, programming-related problem.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs are not staying the same. They are changing so you need to tell search engines *and* users where to find the content. 301 redirects are *exactly* what you want. They tell search engines where to find the new content and to update their indexes (plus Google will transfer PageRank) plus when users go to the old URL they are automatically redirected to the new URL which canonical URLs do not do.

Comment: What I meant is that the request URI remains the same. Thank You!